# Definition of Coboundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was reading [these lecture notes](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall06/cps296.1/Lectures/sec-IV-4.pdf) from Duke University and found a typo I think.  If it's not a  typo then I'm really confused.  Anyway, on page $95$ shouldn't

$$B^p=\operatorname{im}\delta^{p+1}:C^{p+1}\to C^{p}$$
actually be
$$B^p=\operatorname{im}\delta^{p-1}:C^{p-1}\to C^{p}\, ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The first displayed formula on page $95$ is

$$ \delta^{p-1} : \operatorname{Hom}(\mathsf{C}_{p-1}, G) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathsf{C}_p, G)$$

and on the first line of that page (before the displayed formula), $\mathsf{C}^p$ is defined as $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathsf{C}_p, G)$. With this definition, the above can be rewritten as

$$\delta^{p-1} : \mathsf{C}^{p-1} \to \mathsf{C}^p.$$

Further down the page, the diagram indicates that $B^p \subseteq Z^p \subseteq \mathsf{C}^p$ (which is necessary for cohomology to be defined). The only way that $B^p$, defined as the image of some coboundary map, will be a subset of $\mathsf{C}^p$ is if $B^p$ is defined as $\operatorname{im}\delta^{p-1} : \mathsf{C}^{p-1} \to \mathsf{C}^p$.